# zsh-completions error when loading `zsh: compinit: function definition file not found`

Tags: shell, autocomplete, homebrew, zsh

After trying to move back from oh-my-zsh to a lighter zsh configuration I've installed the `zsh-completions` plugin which requires to have the following when installed via homebrew:

```
if type brew &>/dev/null; then
    fpath=${HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/share/zsh-completions:$fpath

    autoload -Uz compinit
    compinit
fi
```

Problem is that it does not work properly as it can't find `compinit` and I got the next error:

```
zsh: compinit: function definition file not found
```

Comment: The first line checks that `brew` is installed. What happens if you remove the if-statement and restart your terminal emulator (or simply source your `.zshrc`-file)? If that works, then you know that it's something with that if-statement. If it still doesn't work, then you could write `brew config | grep HOMEBREW_PREFIX` to see what `HOMEBREW_PREFIX` points to (and add that to the question). And please also add other lines that touches `$fpath` in your `.zshrc`-file. And perhaps also try and echo the entire line ( `echo $fpath` ) - and add that to the question as well.

Comment: It definitely had sth to do with `fpath`, basically  `fpath=${HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/share/zsh-completions:$fpath` is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

maybe it's Lmod that cause the problem. See this article:
[Lmod FAQ](https://lmod.readthedocs.io/en/latest/040_FAQ.html)

> **If my startup shell is bash or tcsh and I start zsh, why do I get a message that is like: “/etc/zsh/zshrc:48: compinit: function definition file not found”**
> Lmod supports both zsh and ksh. Both these shell use shell var. FPATH but in very different ways. The issue is that some bash or tcsh users run ksh scripts and need access to the module command. In the K-shell, the env. var. FPATH is exported and is the path to where the module shell function is found. Z-shell also uses FPATH to point to tool like compinit and others. By exporting FPATH, Z-shell does not change the value of FPATH which means that the zsh user can not find all the functions that make it work.
> The solution is to add “unset FPATH” in your startup files before “exec zsh”.

In my case I have to uninstall the Lmod to ensure that both direct ssh and VSCode terminal run zsh completion correctly.

Comment: This helped me solve my problem: I've installed zsh via conda, and ran into the OP's problem. Unsetting FPATH fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

After seeing the value set using `echo $fpath` I realised that homebrew caveat suggestion had the wrong code and it didn't include the folder where compinit function is.

The fix is can be done easily, replacing:

```
fpath=${HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/share/zsh-completions:$fpath
```

with

```
export fpath=(${HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/share/zsh-completions $fpath)
```

fixed the problem.

Comment: The export is unnecessary, both because it's `zsh` itself (and not a child process) that needs `fpath`, and because you can't export an array in any case.

Comment: If you *wanted* to use a colon-separated list of directories, the correct variable is `FPATH`. (`FPATH` is the "real" variable; `fpath` is an array that's "tied" to `FPATH`. Changes to one are reflected in the other, so they just provide two different interfaces to the same configuration.)

Comment: You're absolutely right, will delete de answer. feel free to add a answer and will accept it

Comment: The answer doesn't need to be deleted. `fpath=(...)` is perfectly correct without the `export` command. The relationship between `fpath` and `FPATH` is more of an FYI comment.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, after update **macOS** to:

```
ProductName:        macOS
ProductVersion:     13.3
BuildVersion:       22E252
```

I had problem with `zsh`:

```
/Users/myuser/.zshrc:13: compinit: function definition file not found
```

**Wrong** `.zshrc`:

```bash
fpath=(~/.zsh/completion /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions /usr/share/zsh/site-functions /usr/share/zsh/5.8.1/functions)
```

Because directory with name `5.8.1` didn't exist and completes didn't load.

### Solution

- Need to change directory name to correct
- add autoload for `compinit`

**Correct** `.zshrs`:

```
fpath=(~/.zsh/completion /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions /usr/share/zsh/site-functions /usr/share/zsh/5.9/functions)

autoload -Uz compinit && compinit
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed the zsh from source with prefix to my home. I got this same error, and found out that the new zsh does not have its functions folder on its fpath by default.

```
fpath=($fpath [prefix]/share/zsh/[version]/functions)
```

in the beginning of my ~/.zshrc solved the problem. Where

- [prefix] points to the --prefix where I installed zsh
- [version] varies based on zsh's version

Answer (score -3):

for me, It's the privilege, after fix them, it works well.

```bash
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/lib/zsh
sudo chmod a+r /usr/local/lib/zsh
sudo chmod a+r /usr/local/lib/zsh/5.9
sudo chmod a+r /usr/local/lib/zsh/5.9/zsh
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/lib/zsh/5.9
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/share/zsh
sudo chmod a+r /usr/local/share/zsh
sudo chmod a+xr /usr/local/share/zsh/5.9
```